# The unique existence of a harmonic function $u$ that agrees with a continuous function $h$ on the smooth boundary of a domain

Tags: harmonic-functions

I'm reading below statement at page 36 of these [notes](https://ipgold.epfl.ch/%7Eleveque/Lecture_Notes/sc2_final.pdf), i.e.,

---

> [image]

**Fact.** Let $D$ be an open and bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\partial D$ be its (smooth) boundary. Let $h \in \mathcal{C}(\partial D)$. Then there exists a unique function $u \in \mathcal{C}^2(D)$ such that
$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta u(\underline{x})=0, & \forall \underline{x} \in D, \\ u(\underline{x})=h(\underline{x}), & \forall \underline{x} \in \partial D .
\end{cases}
$$

**Remark.** The function $u$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}$ (not in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ).

---

Could you confirm if my below understanding is fine?

1. $h:\partial D \to \mathbb R$ is continuous.
2. $u: \overline D \to \mathbb R$ is twice continuously differentiable. Here $\overline D$ is the closure of $D$ in $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. No, $u$ is twice continuously differentiable in $D$ (i.e. in its interior), but only continuous on the boundary $\partial D$. Thus, one usually writes $u\in C^2(D)\cap C(\overline{D})$.

Of course, you could assume $u\in C^2(\overline{D})$, but it is not necessary for the theory of this type of PDEs.

Comment: I think you meant $u\in C(D)\cap C^2(\overline{D})$ rather than $u\in C^2(D)\cap C(\overline{D})$.

Comment: @Akira No, that would be a trivial statement: $C^2(\overline{ D})$  is a subset of $C(D)$, so their intersection would be just $C^2(\overline{ D})$.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry for being silly.

Comment: Could you have a look at my related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4658507/a-relation-between-dirichlet-problem-and-brownian-motion)?